# how to increment values inside a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this

```
|Rank|Location|Items|
---------------------
|    |Japan   |45   |
|    |China   |31   |
|    |Korea   |10   |
```

i want the result to be like this

```
|Rank|Location|Items|
---------------------
|   1|Japan   |45   |
|   2|China   |31   |
|   3|Korea   |10   |
```

I used php because i get the data of the location and items from a database then i used a while loop to print the data from the database to the table. Inside the while loop, I tried putting a $i=1 then a $i++ for the ranking but it doesn't seem to work because it did not increment. Am i Doing it wrong or is there another way? 
Here is my code:

```
<?php

            $server = mysql_connect("localhost","root", "");
            $db =  mysql_select_db("cvgcrm",$server);
            $query = mysql_query("select cf_795, count(*) as Referrals from vtiger_leadscf group by cf_795 order by Referrals DESC");
        ?>

        <table class="striped">
        <table align="center">
            <tr class="header">
                <td>Rank</td>
                <td>Location</td>
                <td>Items</td>
            </tr>

            <?php
               while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                   $i = 1;
                   echo "<tr>";
                   echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$row[location]."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$row[items]."</td>"; 
                   echo "</tr>";
                   $i=$i+1;
               }

            ?>
```

Comment: This PHP code is using the deprecated **mysql** interface. New development should use either **PDO** or **mysqli**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

place `$i=1` out side your loop

```
    <?php
       $i=1;
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {               
           echo "<tr>";
           echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
           echo "<td>".$row[location]."</td>";
           echo "<td>".$row[items]."</td>"; 
           echo "</tr>";
           $i=$i++;
       } 
    ?>
```